# Change SVG Fill on hover

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to change the Path #Fill-1 fill color on hover.

```
 <svg version="1.1"  id="Layer_1" 
        <g id="UI-Kit" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g id="Icons" transform="translate(-86.000000, -283.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
                <g id="Fill-1-_x2B_-Fill-2-_x2B_-Fill-3" transform="translate(86.000000, 283.000000)" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                    <path id="Fill-1" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#FFA400" d="M22.166,0.184c-12.161,0-22.054,9.893-22.054,22.054
                        s9.893,22.054,22.054,22.054s22.055-9.894,22.055-22.054S34.327,0.184,22.166,0.184"/>

                    <path id="Fill-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M23.906,22.229c0-2.794,0.002-5.588-0.002-8.382
                        c-1.084-0.016-1.998-0.959-2.026-2.039c-0.003-0.133-0.005-0.266-0.005-0.398V22.229"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        </svg>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
svg > path#Fill-1:hover {
    fill:red;
}
```

But nothing happens on hover. please check the JSfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/vww63s0s/

Answer (score 2):

You can just reference Fill-1 directly since it's an ID.

```css
#Fill-1:hover {
    fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"  id="Layer_1" class="red">
        <g id="UI-Kit" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g id="Icons" transform="translate(-86.000000, -283.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
                <g id="Fill-1-_x2B_-Fill-2-_x2B_-Fill-3" transform="translate(86.000000, 283.000000)" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                    <path id="Fill-1"sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#FFA400" d="M22.166,0.184c-12.161,0-22.054,9.893-22.054,22.054
                        s9.893,22.054,22.054,22.054s22.055-9.894,22.055-22.054S34.327,0.184,22.166,0.184"/>

                    <path id="Fill-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M23.906,22.229c0-2.794,0.002-5.588-0.002-8.382
                        c-1.084-0.016-1.998-0.959-2.026-2.039c-0.003-0.133-0.005-0.266-0.005-0.398V22.229"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: it`s not working because the button : please check : http://jsfiddle.net/vww63s0s/

Comment: @MohamedSamy -  Your question didn't have an SVG file inside of a button though.

Comment: @MohamedSamy - You can't change your question after someone's submitted an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

the `>` means that you're going to look for a path that is **directly** inside the svg, but there are a couple g elements in between. Remove the `>`, and it should work

Comment: Was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/vww63s0s/3/) what you're after? If so, I'll edit my answer to explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

Use svg as the parent, and then change the inner element on hover. The codes below should do the job.

```
 svg #Fill-1 { 
     fill:red;
 }
 svg:hover #Fill-1 {
     fill:black;
 }
```